# combine two rails each methods to order by lowest price

Tags: ruby-on-rails

heres my code

```
  <% @event.skiddle_tickets.reorder(:face_value).each do |skiddle| %>
  <% if skiddle.quantity == "0 available" || skiddle.face_value == "0.00" || skiddle.name["Coach"] %>
<% else %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <p>
          <strong><%= skiddle.name %></strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= number_to_currency(skiddle.face_value.to_f + skiddle.booking_fee.to_f, unit: "£") %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= link_to "Buy Now", @event.skiddle_url, class: "btn btn-info" %>
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" align="center" style="border-left-style: dotted; padding:27px 0">
        <%= image_tag("skiddle-logo.png", style: "width: 140px") %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% @stubhub_tickets.each do |stubhub| %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <p>
          <strong><%= stubhub["sectionName"] %></strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= number_to_currency(stubhub["currentPrice"]["amount"], unit: "£") %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= link_to "Buy Now", @event.skiddle_url, class: "btn btn-info" %>
        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" align="center" style="border-left-style: dotted; padding:14px 0">
        <%= image_tag("stubhub-logo.png", style: "width: 140px") %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

These are clearly two each methods, the problem is that one of these stacks on the of the other one. What I'm wanting is to have the tickets order together rather than separately.

What would be the best method of doing this? I thought it would be to combine the two selectors together and then order on price but the prices are given from the backend differently and renaming is a nightmare.

I'm open to javascript or any other type of solutions if needed.

**Edit**

So i'm not fully understanding the second part to this, Will open another question if needed.

So i'm trying to add ticketmaster into the mix, Ticketmaster only have one price.

What i have so far is this

```
ticketmaster = Ticketmasters.where(merchant_product_id: @event.ticketmaster)
stubhub = []
skiddle = @event.skiddle_tickets.sort_by {|x| [x.face_value + x.booking_fee] }
if @stubhub_tickets.present?
  stubhub = @stubhub_tickets.sort_by {|x| x['currentPrice']['amount'] }
end


@sort = []


loop do
  # break if skiddle.empty? || stubhub.empty?
  @sort << ((skiddle.first.face_value + skiddle.first.booking_fee).to_f < stubhub.first['currentPrice']['amount'].to_f < ticketmaster.search_price ? skiddle.shift() : stubhub.shift(): ticketmaster.shift())
end

@tickets = @sort + skiddle + stubhub + ticketmaster
```

Comment: Check the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to sort 2 differents arrays, I will try to split the problem into 2 phases:

**1.** Order each array
**2.** Create a new array, comparing the fist element of both arrays, and taking that element into the new array, and the repeat until one array is empty. Finally, add the rest of the arrays to the new array.

So I would try, in your controller, something like this:

```
# sort skiddle_tickets and stubhub_tickets
skiddle = event.skiddle_tickets.sort_by {|x| [x.face_value + x.booking_fee] }
stubhub = stubhub_tickets.sort_by {|x| [x.currentPrice.amount] }

#merge both sorted arrays in a single one
@sort = []

loop do
  break if skiddle.empty? || stubhub.empty?
  @sort << ((skiddle.first.face_value + skiddle.first.booking_fee) < stubhub.first.currentPrice.amount ? skiddle.shift() : stubhub.shift())
end

@sort_list = @sort + skiddle + stubhub
```

And then you can iterate over `@sort_list` in your view, but you have to check in every iteration if the element is a skiddle or a stubhub in order to provide the proper printing.

#### Edit:

Here the documentacion of [Shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/shift).

---

#### Edit 2:

As the OP is struggling with the idea of this solution, here a more general explanation.

Suppose you have 3 models with values of price:

```
ModelA => The price is face_value + booking_fee
ModelB => The price is current_price
ModelC => The price is in my_price
```

Let's say we have this values:

```
|           ModelA         | price |
|--------------------------|-------|
| face_value + booking_fee |  800  |
| face_value + booking_fee |  400  |
| face_value + booking_fee |  100  |

|    ModelB     | price |
|---------------|-------|
| current_price |  600  |
| current_price |  900  |
| current_price |  200  |


|    ModelC     | price |
|---------------|-------|
| my_price      |  500  |
| my_price      |  500  |
| my_price      |  300  |
```

And the goal is to sort all values (from the 3 models) in ascending order of price, here my approach.

**Step 1:** sort all the arrays:

```
modelA = ModelA.all.sort_by {|x| [x.face_value + x.booking_fee] }
modelB = ModelB.all.sort_by {|x| [x.current_price] }
modelC = ModelC.all.sort_by {|x| [x.my_price] }
```

Now, you have all your arrays sorted, like this:

```
|           ModelA         | price |
|--------------------------|-------|
| face_value + booking_fee |  100  |
| face_value + booking_fee |  400  |
| face_value + booking_fee |  800  |


|    ModelB     | price |
|---------------|-------|
| current_price |  200  |
| current_price |  600  |
| current_price |  900  |


|    ModelC     | price |
|---------------|-------|
| my_price      |  300  |
| my_price      |  500  |
| my_price      |  500  |
```

**Step 2:** compare all the firs elements of the arrays, and find the lowest:

```
|           ModelA        | price |
|-------------------------|-------|
| face_value + booking_fee|  100  |

|    ModelB     | price |
|---------------|-------|
| current_price |  200  |

|    ModelC     | price |
|---------------|-------|
| my_price      |  300  |
```

Now you have the lowest price of all the arrays.

**Step 3:** remove the lowest from the original array and insert it in the new array:

Insert:

```
|         new_array        | price |
|--------------------------|-------|
| face_value + booking_fee |  100  |
```

Delete:

```
|           ModelA         | price |
|--------------------------|-------|
| face_value + booking_fee |  100  |
```

So, now what you have is the lowest of all prices inserted in the new array.

Repeat **Step 2**, and the magic here is that the arrays are sorted already and the lowest price had been removed, so what you have now are the remaining prices.

Comment: So i have tested this and have undefined method current price (event though current price is populated)

the next question is, you said that the i'd need to check every iteration, however i dont understand the best way of getting this into the view because one displays it one way and the other another way?

Comment: Also the .pop doesnt work, Returns undefined method?

Comment: @ samnymr I've change the `pop` method for `shift` in the answer (and added a link to documentation). And for you to be able to solve your problem, dont take my answer as a copy and paste solution, you need to sort 2 different model data, so try to understand what I did and implement your solution based on this recomendation.

Comment: As for the way to show your information in your view, you are already doing it, when you `skiddle` and `stubhub`, the thing is that you need to check in the sort array for every element, in order to provide one printing or the other, that make sense to you?

Comment: Hi Alejando, One last question, If i was to have a bunch more tables to put together how would i do this?

Sam

Comment: @samnymr You will need to sort every Model (table) and perform something I did in the loop (ask for every Model for the lowest value, and take that value from the original array into the new ordered array). A good idea might be to have similar fields to compare in the models.

Comment: Adding them to the array is the bit im getting stuck on, Would that be done via the @sort method? Say if i had another table called tickets. Would i add `< tickets.first.price` after the stubhub one and then add ticket.shift in?

Comment: You need to divide your problem, **1)** Sort every *array* (skiddle, stubhub, ...) with the `sort_by` method or any other way you find. in this way , you will have every **array** in order of price. **2)** Combine all the arrays, do this taking all your arrays' first positions and performing a comparation of all of them, and when you get the lowest value of this values, remove that value from the array and inserted in the new array (with `<<`).

Comment: Would you mind telling me in the edit where i have gone fully wrong with this?

Sam